# A rational function f(x) has the following power series representation for the interval $-3<x<3$. $f(x) = x -\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x^3}{3^2}+...$

Tags: power-series

A rational function f(x) has the following power series representation for the interval $-3<x<3$. $f(x) = x - \frac{x^2}{3} + \frac{x^3}{3^2} +...$. Find a closed-form expression for f(x).

Now, I found that $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{-1}{3})^{n-1}(x)^n$, but how do I continue from here.

Comment: Recognize a geometric series.

Comment: Yes I recognised this but the 'x' is not to the same power as the $\frac{-1}{3}$ doesn't this pose a problem?

Comment: First term $x$, common ratio $-\frac{x}{3}$.  Now can you find the sum?

Comment: Does that mean the closed form expression is $\frac{x(1-(\frac{-x}{3})^n}{1-(\frac{-x}{3})}$

Comment: It is an **infinite** geometric series, sum $\frac{x}{1+x/3}$, which maybe looks better as $\frac{3x}{3+x}$. Note that for convergence we need $|x/3|\lt 1$, so $|x|\lt 3$.

Comment: where did $\frac{x}{1+x/3}$ come from?

Comment: You may recall that if $|r|\lt 1$ the infinite geometric series $a+ar+ar^2+\cdots$ has sum $\frac{a}{1-r}$. Here $a=x$ and $r=-x/3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the terms
to have the same exponent
for everything,
just make it happen:

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{-1}{3})^{n-1}(x)^n\\
&=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{-1}{3})^{n-1}(x)^{n-1}
\qquad\text{(pull x out so exponents the same)}\\
&=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{-1}{3})^{n}(x)^{n}
\qquad\text{(shift exponents)}\\
&=x\frac1{1-\frac{-x}{3}}\\
&=\frac{x}{1+\frac{x}{3}}\\
&=\frac{3x}{3+x}
\qquad\text{(this is optional)}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much ;)